# Qt5 Micro build for 8MB Mb embedded

Tags: qt, embedded-linux, openwrt

Would it be possible to use Qt for an embedded project on a very restricted system, which runs one 8MB Falsh and 32MB ram OpenWRT (typical router configuration).

The goal is not to use the GUI, but rather all the non-gui classes and signal/slot concept for productivity purpose.

So far two solution are to be explored, minimal build, but this seems to still take a few MB.

Static build, but difficult to evaluate the final size.

Any experienced feedback would be welcome, to know if it's worthy to spend time to attempt this or if it's a lost cause, in which case what alternative would be good ?

Cheers

Comment: This is one of those questions that is quite tricky to answer, so it depends entirely on what you want from Qt. There's plenty of Qt that has hard requirements on importing the GUI libraries, such as QWebKit, and a lot of the non-GUI libraries are incredibly heavy.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a custom Qt build and disable all the features that you won't be using. See [this configure doc page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/configure-options.html#including-or-excluding-features), and [qfeatures.txt - the list of configurable features](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/global/qfeatures.txt).

A statically built 32 bit Qt 5 executable for Windows that has no dependencies other than system dlls and includes core, gui, widgets and network modules, with no features disabled, and a small application takes about 6MB. So, if you compress the executable and get rid of unneded features, you should occupy <4MB.

It seems possible on your system, as long as you can squeeze the kernel there too. Most likely, you'd be putting the necessary kernel modules, startup scripts, busybox and your static executable on a squashfs that gets mounted as a root filesystem. The squashfs needs to be compiled into the kernel, not as a separate module.

The flash would contain the bootloader, the kernel, a squashfs, and probably a megabyte to spare or so.

Comment: Indeed, it seems a bit too challenging, as the system has to run on it as well. I think i'll let this idea down

Comment: @Damien I think you read it wrong: given that your system could run a full-blown GUI application and still have some space left, I don't think that non-GUI code will be a problem. A stripped down Qt with core and network modules, with unneeded features turned off, will take well under 2MB.

Comment: Do you have any reference ? so far what i see is more on the 6 MB range.

Comment: @Damien There must be something fundamentally misconfigured then, perhaps you're not stripping the symbol information from the executable? You are statically linking, and this is a fully optimized build with link-time code generation on a recent compiler, right? And are you talking about the final executable size? The `.a` libraries will be much bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example from the `Embedded Linux Projects Using Yocto Project Cookbook` to optimize the kernel and rootfs.

> By default, the compressed Linux kernel image (zImage) for the
>   wandboard-quad is around
>   5.2 MB. This recipe will show how we can reduce that.
>
> An example of a minimal kernel configuration for a Wandboard that is
>   able to boot from a microSD card root filesystem is the
>   arch/arm/configs/wandboard-quad_minimal_ defconfig file that follows:
>
> ```
> CONFIG_KERNEL_XZ=y
> CONFIG_NO_HZ=y
> CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS=y
> CONFIG_BLK_DEV_INITRD=y
> CONFIG_CC_OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE=y
> CONFIG_EMBEDDED=y
> CONFIG_SLOB=y
> CONFIG_ARCH_MXC=y
> CONFIG_SOC_IMX6Q=y
> CONFIG_SOC_IMX6SL=y
> CONFIG_SMP=y
> CONFIG_VMSPLIT_2G=y
> CONFIG_AEABI=y
> CONFIG_CPU_FREQ=y
> CONFIG_ARM_IMX6_CPUFREQ=y
> CONFIG_CPU_IDLE=y
> CONFIG_VFP=y
> CONFIG_NEON=y
> CONFIG_DEVTMPFS=y
> CONFIG_DEVTMPFS_MOUNT=y
> CONFIG_PROC_DEVICETREE=y
> CONFIG_SERIAL_IMX=y
> CONFIG_SERIAL_IMX_CONSOLE=y
> CONFIG_REGULATOR=y
> CONFIG_REGULATOR_ANATOP=y
> CONFIG_MMC=y
> CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI=y
> CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI_PLTFM=y
> CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI_ESDHC_IMX=y
> CONFIG_DMADEVICES=y
> CONFIG_IMX_SDMA=y
> CONFIG_EXT3_FS=y
> ```
>
> This configuration builds an 886 K compressed Linux kernel image
>   (zImage).
>
> An example of a small image, core-image-small , that does not include
>   the packagegroup- core-boot recipe and can be used as the base for a
>   root filesystem image with reduced size,
>   recipes-core/images/core-image-small.bb , is shown next:
>
> ```
> DESCRIPTION = "Minimal console image."
> IMAGE_INSTALL= "\
> base-files \
> base-passwd \
> busybox \
> sysvinit \
> initscripts \
> ${ROOTFS_PKGMANAGE_BOOTSTRAP} \
> ${CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL} \
> "
> IMAGE_LINGUAS = " "
> LICENSE = "MIT"
> inherit core-image
> IMAGE_ROOTFS_SIZE ?= "8192"
> DISTRO = "poky-tiny"
> INSANE_SKIP_glibc-locale = "installed-vs-shipped"
> ```
>
> With poky-tiny , the size of the image is further reduced to around 4
>   MB.

All that left is how you configure Qt to meet the requirement.